# Why can't I add a mask to UITableViewCell's contentView?

Tags: iphone, ios, uikit

Is this not possible?

I've tried this:

```
    UIBezierPath *maskPath;
maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(20, 20, 200, 30) byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerTopRight | UIRectCornerTopLeft) cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(8.0, 8.0)];

CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
maskLayer.frame = self.bounds;
maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
maskLayer.fillColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;

self.contentView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
self.contentView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

and nothing happens. However, if do the same thing upon another view in the contentView, the mask works as expected. What gives?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question but I wanted to point out that you don't seem to be assigning self.maskLayer to the maskLayer that you initialize in your code snippet.  I imagine that could be causing some weird bugs.

Comment: ya that was a typo thanks

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me if I took the "contentView" out of your last two lines of code. I don't know why that works, maybe you can't mask the content view?